# Using 8-bit instead of 16-bit in Adafruit library

Tags: spi

I tried to modify the Adafruit_GFX and Adafruit_ST7735 libraries to make the color variable( as shown in code below) to use 8-bit instead of 16-bit for displaying 8-bit color on LCD screen.

```
void Adafruit_ST7735::pushColor(uint16_t color) {
 #if defined (SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION)
   SPI.beginTransaction(mySPISettings);
 #endif
  *rsport |=  rspinmask;
  *csport &= ~cspinmask;

   spiwrite(color >> 8);
   spiwrite(color);

   *csport |= cspinmask;
 #if defined (SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION)
   SPI.endTransaction();
 #endif
}
```

I changed it to the below

```
void Adafruit_ST7735::pushColor(uint8_t color) {
  #if defined (SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION)
   SPI.beginTransaction(mySPISettings);
  #endif
   *rsport |=  rspinmask;
   *csport &= ~cspinmask;

   //spiwrite(color);
   spiwrite(color);

   *csport |= cspinmask;
#if defined (SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION)
  SPI.endTransaction();
#endif
}
```

I have made similar changes in other portions of the code. This time nothing was displayed in the LCD(it was blank). However, when the spiwrite(color) is written twice i.e. the comment is removed, the code works fine. 
Why is there a need to write 'spiwrite' function twice even in case of 8-bit color?

The original Adafruit library files are also attached.
[drive.google.com/open?id=0B3x_NfKXnhtHR0VBcTNZbk5WT0E](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3x_NfKXnhtHR0VBcTNZbk5WT0E)

Comment: If there is a publicly available version of the library that we can easily view online, why do you make us download a .zip file from Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the datasheet of the LCD screen? The LCD expects you to
send the data in a specific format, and you should comply with that
format rather than invent your own and expect it to magically understand
it. If the LCD expects you to send 16 bits, you should do so. Or maybe
it has a 8 bit mode and there is a way for you to tell it “I'm switching
to 8-bit mode”. Read the datasheet to be sure.

If you want to display 8-bit color on an LCD expecting 16-bit, you
should find a way to map the 8-bit values into 16-bit values. The most
obvious way to map the range [0, 255] to [0, 65535] is to multiply the
8-bit numbers by 65535/255 = 257. Which is the same as sending the byte
twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you / someone asked an identical question here recently.

you didn't say a reason why you want to change a 16-bit type to 8-bit type.

with that said, this should work:

```
void Adafruit_ST7735::pushColor(uint8_t color_msb, uint8_t color_lsb) {
   ...
   spiwrite(color_msb);
   spiwrite(color_lsb);
   ...
```

basically, the original code.